# TypeFace fonts resets itself ? Android studio

Tags: android, android-typeface

I have my own function call that selects type face based on a String.

```
Typeface typeface = getTypeface (activity, fontFamily);
Typeface getTypeface (Activity activity, String fontName) {
    Typeface type = null;

    if (fontName.equals("droidsans") || fontName.equals("normal")) {
        type = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
    } else if (fontName.equals("droidserif") || fontName.equals("serif")) {
        type = Typeface.SERIF;
    } else if (fontName.equals("droidsansmono") || fontName.equals("monospace")) {
        type = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
    } else {
        type = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
    }
    return type;
}
```

This is fairly simple , however, when the breakpoint hits type = Monospace it  or Serif.  The breakpoint will go back to type = Sans_serif.

Thus making my type face equal to Sans_serif instead of monospace.

Why does it sometimes do that???

Comment: Did you check what the value actually is? If you step through your code with a debugger you may see strange "jumps" especially with optimized code. This is, when the debugger cannot accurately match the location to source code lines.

Comment: Hi Henry, I did see strange "jumps" (how do I fix that?) and when i checked the value it was matching what the strange jump suggested. So it would sometimes jumped from `type = Typeface.MONOSPACE;` to `type =  Typeface.SANS_SERIF;` and the end result is `type =  Typeface.SANS_SERIF;`  *sadface*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. I changed else if statement to Switch statement. It seems TypeFace may have some weird issue with else-if??

```
   switch(fontName)
        {
            case "droidsansmono":
            case "monospace":
                type = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
                break;
            case "droidserif":
            case "serif":
                type = Typeface.SERIF;
                break;
            default:
                type =  Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
                break;
        }
         return type;
```

This solved the problem of `type= Typeface.SERIF`, jumping into `type =  Typeface.SANS_SERIF;` with the original if statement code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 fontName.toLowerCase().equal("monospace")
```

Comment: It's hitting the monospace, so type is first casted as monospace, then the break point goes back to the previous if statement

Comment: Does that happen to you?